# http request with json parameter : 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: json, rest, http, jax-rs

i want to know if it's possible to make get call with json into parameter like this?

```
MYJSON ={"Report Name":"Test1"," test: test", ......}
"http://------/getObjects?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rtId=" + rtId + "&params=" + MYJSON;
```

and server side :

```
@GET
@Path("/getObjects")
public Response getObjects(@QueryParam("rtId") String rtId, @QueryParam("params") JsonParam jp){
```

when i test with postMan the url : 
http://-----/getObjects?callback=angular.callbacks._2&rtId=OR:wt.query.template.ReportTemplate:164019&params={%22Report%20Name%22:%22Test1%22}

i get 400 BAD REQUESTE

if it's not possible. How can i make a get call with json object?

Thanks :)

Comment: do you want to send json data to server ?

Comment: yes ! i had all ready implement the service getObjects() in the server

Comment: why are you passing JSON payload as query parameter? you are abusing the GET method, you better come-up with a meaningful URI to access your resource.

Comment: @LeTex so how can i pass my json object?

Comment: first of all, why are you using GET method, are you trying to get resource? if yes, why are you passing payload like JSON?. GET method is meant for accessing resources not posting/putting resource.
 sometin like :  GET /users/{user_id}

If your requirement could fit into POST method, then you can pass the JSON as POST method payload.

Comment: @LeTex yes i'm trying to get resource. Finally, i found that the problem was that Angular $http.jsonp(url) didn't parse all special character at the URL like "{" & "}". So i convert them my self "{" to %7D and "}" to %7B. And it's works